# Hide/Show non first letters in an element and all childs - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide/show all non-first letters only in a div and all children nodes on click

Text Target:

> 37 Jesus replied: “‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’[a] 38 This is the first and greatest commandment. 39 And the second is like it: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’[b]

On click:

> 37 J____ r_____: “‘L___ t__ L___ y__ G__ w___ a__ y___ h___ a__ w___ a__ y__ s__ a__ w___ a__ y__ m___.’[a] 38 T___ i_ t__ f_____ a__ g__________ c___________. 39 A__ t__ s_______ i_ l___ i_: ‘L___ y___ n_________ a_ y_______.’[b]

If click again, show original and so on.

```js
var original=$('#votd').html();
function isLetter(chr){
   return chr.toUpperCase()!=chr.toLowerCase();
}
$('#votd').on('click', function() {
text=$(this).text();
if (!text.includes('_')){
    $(this).find('*').each(function(index,value){
  str=$(this).text();
  newStr='';
  for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++ ) {
   chr=str[i];
   priorChar='';
   isFirstLetterInWord=isLetter(chr)&&!isLetter(priorChar);
   if(i>0){
    if(!isFirstLetterInWord&&isLetter(chr)){
     newStr+='_';
    }else{
     newStr+=chr;
    }
   }else{
    newStr+=chr;
    priorChar=str[i];
   }
  } 
  $(this).text(newStr);
 }
}else{
 $('#votd').html(original);
}  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="votd"><span><sup>37&nbsp;</sup>Jesus replied: <span>“‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’<sup data-fn="#frp-passage-0-23910a" class="footnote" data-link="[<a href=&quot;#frp-passage-0-23910a&quot; title=&quot;See footnote a&quot;>a</a>]">[<a>a</a>]</sup><sup class="crossreference" data-link="(<a href=&quot;#crp-passage-0-23910A&quot; title=&quot;See cross-reference A&quot;>A</a>)" data-cr="#crp-passage-0-23910A"></sup></span></span> <span><span><sup>38&nbsp;</sup>This is the first and greatest commandment.</span></span> <span><span><sup>39&nbsp;</sup>And the second is like it: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’<sup data-fn="#frp-passage-0-23912b" class="footnote" data-link="[<a href=&quot;#frp-passage-0-23912b&quot; title=&quot;See footnote b&quot;>b</a>]">[<a>b</a>]</sup><sup class="crossreference" data-link="(<a href=&quot;#crp-passage-0-23912B&quot; title=&quot;See cross-reference B&quot;>B</a>)" data-cr="#crp-passage-0-23912B"></sup></span></span></p>
```

But it doesn't work, can u help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `votdWords`? Don't see any class `nl` either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the regular expression `/(?<=\b[\w]+)[^\d\W]/g` to target every characters to convert. Then with `if(myString === $('#votd').text())` you verify which conversion you have to do. Then when you have to convert the element value, use `.replace()` with the `regex` that you made and change it to `_` character. If the value equal not the original value, convert it back to the original version as below.

```js
var regex = /(?<=\b[\w]+)[^\d\W]/g;
myString = $('#votd').text();

$("#votd").on("click", function() {
  if(myString === $('#votd').text()) $('#votd').text(myString.replace(regex, '_'));
  else $('#votd').text(myString);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="votd"><span><sup>37&nbsp;</sup>Jesus replied: <span>“‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’<sup data-fn="#frp-passage-0-23910a" class="footnote" data-link="[<a href=&quot;#frp-passage-0-23910a&quot; title=&quot;See footnote a&quot;>a</a>]">[<a>a</a>]</sup><sup class="crossreference" data-link="(<a href=&quot;#crp-passage-0-23910A&quot; title=&quot;See cross-reference A&quot;>A</a>)" data-cr="#crp-passage-0-23910A"></sup></span></span> <span><span><sup>38&nbsp;</sup>This is the first and greatest commandment.</span></span> <span><span><sup>39&nbsp;</sup>And the second is like it: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’<sup data-fn="#frp-passage-0-23912b" class="footnote" data-link="[<a href=&quot;#frp-passage-0-23912b&quot; title=&quot;See footnote b&quot;>b</a>]">[<a>b</a>]</sup><sup class="crossreference" data-link="(<a href=&quot;#crp-passage-0-23912B&quot; title=&quot;See cross-reference B&quot;>B</a>)" data-cr="#crp-passage-0-23912B"></sup></span></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used @Jonathan Gagne answer and modified a little regex and code to preserve inner html, and just replace text. Thanks a lot

```js
var regex = /(?<=<[^>]+>[^&<>]*[\wáéíóúñ])[^\d\W]|[áéíóúñ]/g;
html = $('#votd').html();
$("#votd").on("click", function() {
  if (html === $('#votd').html())
    $('#votd').html(html.replace(regex, '_'));
  else
    $('#votd').html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="votd"><span><sup>37&nbsp;</sup>Jesus replied: <span>“‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’<sup data-fn="#frp-passage-0-23910a" class="footnote" data-link="[<a href=&quot;#frp-passage-0-23910a&quot; title=&quot;See footnote a&quot;>a</a>]">[<a>a</a>]</sup><sup class="crossreference" data-link="(<a href=&quot;#crp-passage-0-23910A&quot; title=&quot;See cross-reference A&quot;>A</a>)" data-cr="#crp-passage-0-23910A"></sup></span></span>
  <span><span><sup>38&nbsp;</sup>This is the first and greatest commandment.</span></span> <span><span><sup>39&nbsp;</sup>And the second is like it: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’<sup data-fn="#frp-passage-0-23912b" class="footnote" data-link="[<a href=&quot;#frp-passage-0-23912b&quot; title=&quot;See footnote b&quot;>b</a>]">[<a>b</a>]</sup><sup class="crossreference" data-link="(<a href=&quot;#crp-passage-0-23912B&quot; title=&quot;See cross-reference B&quot;>B</a>)" data-cr="#crp-passage-0-23912B"></sup></span></span>
</p>
```